# Installed Plasma widgets and login screens don't show up

Tags: kubuntu

I downloaded some login screens and Plasma widgets from System Settings in Kubuntu, but they don't show up as selectable options. It says they're installed but I can't choose them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that happens because the widgets you downloaded and installed aren't fully compatible with the KDM Greeter. Not all of the downloadble login screens you see do work, even if they say they're installed.

Comment: Then I guess most don't work because I've tried about 15 different login screens and none show up, I've ugraded to KDE 4.8.1, are most login screens not compatible with that yet?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but going to kde-look.org will show you more information about the login screens